# Maintenance page configuration with dynamic timing in Apache

Tags: apache, maintenance-mode

I have a maintenance page in apache which is working fine with static content. How to configure maintenance page in Apache with Dynamic timing?

Ex : Server will be back by 2 PM GMT.

Comment: It is unclear what you actually ask. What does "dynamic timing" mean? You always need to specify if and until when your service is not available, which makes the information static.

Comment: some configuration file where time can be configured as an attribute and maintenance page can take the value of time.

Comment: Same issue: where should that time parameter come from? You'd have to specify it somewhere manually, so you just push the task one step further but don't save anything.

Comment: But anyway: you can obviously use a trivial php script as maintenance page and have it evaluate a parameter you hand over. Just as with any other page.